# $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of symmetric random walk

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question while studying the probability theory.
Let $X_i$ be iid with $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=1/2$. Put $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$. Then how can I show that $\limsup_n S_n/\sqrt{n}=\infty$ and $\liminf_n S_n/\sqrt{n}=-\infty$ almost surely? By the central limit theorem, $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges to $N(0,1)$ weakly. I tried to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I couldn't figure out how those results come.

Comment: Ha, You need to use Kolmogorove 0-1  law. Note that $\{\lim\sup S_n =\infty\}$ is a tail event and by central limit theorem $\lim P(S_n>\sqrt{n}) >0 $ which implies $P(\lim\sup S_n/\sqrt{n}>1)>0$ and then $P(\lim\sup S_n=\infty )>0$ and is in fact 1.

Comment: @BrianDing Why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

As @saz suggested, I write an answer here which summarize what I comment.

Since $\{\limsup S_n=\infty\}$ is a tail event (not too hard to see this by noting that $\sup_{n\geq v}S_n$ is decreasing in $v\in \mathbb{N}$). So Kolmogorove 0-1 law says that it has probability 0 or 1.

Now by central limit theorem, $\lim P(S_n /\sqrt{n}>1)>0 $ implies  $P(\limsup S_n/\sqrt{n}>1)>0$ and thus $P(\lim\sup S_n=\infty )=1$.

Indeed, in this case, you have  $P(\lim\sup S_n/\sqrt{n}=\infty )=1$ as well since $\{\lim\sup S_n/\sqrt{n}=\infty \}$ is a tail event as well.