# Limit of random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}=+\infty, \quad\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}=-\infty \quad P\text{-a.s.}$$

Here $S_n$ is a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. I managed to show that the $\limsup_{n \to \infty} S_n \to +\infty$ $P\text{-a.s.}$
But, for this I have no idea how to deal with. Could anyone tell me how to show this fact?

Comment: Use Borel Cantelli and the fact that the normal distribution has a positive tail no matter how far out you go (ie that its support is the whole real line)

Comment: Central Limit Theorem   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153822/limsup-and-liminf-of-symmetric-random-walk/1155293#1155293

Comment: Alex's answer works. Also, this follows from the law of iterated logarithm.

Comment: If you just write \limsup_{n\to\infty} instead of \operatorname{lim sup}_{n\to\infty} then, in a displayed rather than inline setting, it appears as $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ with the subscript directly below "limsup".  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$, where the $X_i$'s are your i.i.d. jumps with $\mathbb E[X_i]=0, \mathrm{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$ for $i=1,...,n$. Then the Central Limit Theorem tells you that $$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt {\sigma^2 n}} \to Z \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$ from which you know that $Z$ is unbounded (as the tails of the normal distribution extend to infinity).